# React Children only expected to receive a single react child when using with TouchableWithoutFeedback

Tags: reactjs, react-native, touchablewithoutfeedback

In my application I have a text input, I want to hide the keyboard and lose focus whenever the user clicks anywhere on the screen or closes the keyboard.

I created this function for this:

```
interface DismissKeyBoardProps {
  children?: ReactNode
} 

const DismissKeyboard: React.FC<DismissKeyBoardProps> = ({ children }) => (
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback 
  onPress={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}> {children}
  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
);
```

I use the above method like that:

```
const App: React.FC = () => {

  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
      <SafeAreaView>
        <Text> Test </Text>
        <DismissKeyboard>
          <TextInput placeHolder= {"place holder"}/>
        </DismissKeyboard>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
};
```

However, when I try to run it I get an error:
`React.children.only expected to receive a single React element child.`

I don't understand why am I getting this error, when `DismissKeyBooard` has indeed only one child - `TextInput`.

**Edit:**
I tried the suggested solution like that, but I keep getting the same error.

```
  return (
    <View>
      <SafeAreaView>
        <>
          <DismissKeyboard>
            <TextInput style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}} placeHolder={"hint"}/>
          </DismissKeyboard>
        </>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </View>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your children with `<View>`, I guess it will help you.

```
const DismissKeyboard: React.FC<DismissKeyBoardProps> = ({ children }) => (
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback 
  onPress={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}> 
   <View>
    {children}
   </View>
  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
);
```